# Using Raspberry Pi as a wireless bridge repeater

Tags: wifi, wireless, bridge

I need the Raspberry Pi with 2 wireless interfaces (wlan0 and wlan1) to work as a bridge repeater.
wlan1 is an AP and wlan0 is a client connected to a home wireless router.

Devices connected to the wlan1 AP must be able to ping other devices connected to home wireless router.

I'm finding it difficult to find resources that help me achieve this set-up. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For the DHCP you can use "isc-dhcp-server"

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

For Made access point with an USBStick:

```
wget https://github.com/jenssegers/RTL8188-hostapd/archive/v1.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf v1.1.tar.gz
cd RTL8188-hostapd-1.1/hostapd
sudo make
sudo make install
```

[Complete tutorial](https://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/)

Comment: Will this work for the following scenario?

D1 Connected to Home Wireless Router - 
Raspberry Pi AP extending Home Wireless Router - 
D2 Connected to Raspberry Pi AP - - - 

D2 can ping D1